# Bootstrap.js has to load before jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm try to get the Bootstrap drop down functionality to work, but am noticing something very odd.

For some reason, I have to load the bootstrap.min.js BEFORE jquery in order for the drop down to work.

Here is the code when drop-downs don't work:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, if I switch them around (bootstrap before jquery), drop-down magically works.  I don't understand why this is considering bootstrap needs query to run, otherwise I get an error in Firebug of:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
```

Any explanation and/or help would be great!

Comment: Are you including jQuery twice? Otherwise, Bootstrap.js depends on jQuery, so this shouldn't work.

Comment: No, just calling jquery then bootstrap

Comment: If this is the case, then there's something else going on. A link to a  page that reproduces this issue would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine it is because your calling the dropdown code outside of a

```
 $(document).ready(function() { })
```

If you load bootstrap first, it may finish before the call is actually made to the bootstrap code, but before jquery finishes loading, hence the missing reference. tho its hard to now without seeing the code, are you just using the data-api for the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, using the data-api.  Should I not?

Comment: Yup, added: 
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });