# Bootstrap.js before jQuery.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, accordion

On my page I have jQuery accordion and a Bootstrap carousel. I am including jQuery.js before bootstrap.js. In this case, the accordion won't work.

If I use bootstrap.js before jQuery.js, the accordion will work but then the carousel won't work (which is due to the fact that jQuery isn't loaded).

I have already looked at: [Bootstrap.js has to load before jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714106/bootstrap-js-has-to-load-before-jquery) But this is not the case with me.

As I understand, loading jQuery.js before bootstrap.js is the correct choice but then how would I make the accordion work?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple jqueries or bootstraps on your page?

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery-1.12.0

Comment: I tried using jquery verison 1.9.0 and then the carousel won't work but accordion worked. With jquery 1.12.0 it's the opposite :(

Comment: The carousel doesn't work If jquery version is (1.9.0 or lower) Or (3.0.0 or greater) BUT the carousel works if the jquery version is greater than 1.9.0 and less than 3.0.0. The situation is still the same, only one of them (carousel & accordion) works, Whatever the version of jquery I use.

Answer (score 2):

There is two jquery libraries :

#### 1. Core

#### 2. UI

Thus , the order is :

1. Load `jquery.min.js` (core)

Then :

2. Import `bootstrap.min.js` (Where you have Carousel)

Then ,

3. `jquery.ui.js` (UI) (Where you have accordion)

#### Anyway,   we recommend to wrap all your code when document is ready :

```
 $(function(){

     // All your code here
   
 })
```

---

Try this and tell us :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">


   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap3 does not support *jquery v3.0*. Currently it's _jquery: 1.9.1 - 2_ See [Docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json) and [issues](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834)

Comment: I am using libraries in Order 1. bootstrap.css 2. jquery.js 3. bootstrap.js 4. jquery-ui.js 5. jquery-ui.css and then I have my own script

Comment: I tried the above libraries and the carousel won't work in that case.

Comment: Copy again the libraries , because i make change.. Try again and tell me plz (jquery 3==> jquery2)

Comment: Where did you change jquery 3==> jquery2 ?

Comment: i am sorry, i change now : jquery.2.2.1

Comment: I tried changed libraries i.e. jquery 2.2.1 and Nothing works now. Neither the carousel nor accordion.

Comment: Put jsfiddle.net demo , and we will see

Comment: I'll try to do a fiddle. Never done that before, so may take time. Thanks for looking into my problem.